# Is there a method of generating a simulated region of a world with bathymetry?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, map-making, software-recommendations

I would like to generate a relief map of a portion of imaginary world which would be about the size of Europe. I do not want to define the outline of land masses or bathymetry myself; I want the system to do that automatically, kind of like the way Civilization generates random world maps. I would like to define the balance of land mass versus ocean, and also the ratio of islands to continents (Civilization also does this). It would be an added bonus if the system could draw country boundaries.

What would be the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

You sound like you want some form of **terrain generation system**. There are many of these and they range from the private and open source software systems all the way to commercial systems intended for major gaming, TV and film production.

You should probably seek out advice on the Stack Exchange programming sites or a game development forum for more details.

Comment: interms of SE, this would probably be better asked in one of the gaming or RPG sites.  Programming pages are more focused on coding and trouble shooting bugs than software questions.  There is also also Cartographer's Guild which provides help with map forming though not sure if it would be the way you want.  It could at least give you a good starting point.  https://www.cartographersguild.com/content.php

Comment: ahh reading it again, I do see why you would link it to a programming site as you could potentially ask, how would something like this be programmed.  I still feel though this would be better asked in a gaming community rather than a programming community but I may be wrong.

Comment: Ok, that's kind of what I need is the right terminology to search on.

Comment: Might also look at [procedural world generation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155069/how-does-one-get-started-with-procedural-generation).

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on a comment but this probably would also be an answer too.  [Cartographers Guild](https://www.cartographersguild.com/content.php) is a forum for map maker enthusiasts of various skills ranging from professional to amateur.  At the very least, I am sure you can find information within their forum that would be able to point you in the right direction.